# Scripting msconfig: Looking for a way to add a booting software in command line or other Scripts

Tags: scripting, windows-installer

Is there a way to be able to add a software to the Windows startup boot for Xp and Seven in command line or with any script?

**Here the context:**

I'm curently doing an update of an existing software who is coded with a basic language. The language (neobook5) can only lunch a command line or any script.

The software need to add a executable file (in C://test/programToLunchAtTheStartup.exe) in the booting startup.

Alternative question: Is an .msi can do the trick in an hidden way?

Thank you so much,
best regards

---

Please be indulgent it's my first issue here. If you have any trick to improve my question i'm fully aware. You could make change to my answer, i'm not a good english writer.

Comment: Can you edit the registry? That's ultimately what msconfig does.

Comment: Yes i could edit the registry. Note: i could also use an windows installer build with something like Innosetup i guess? But i have the felling that it would be heavy to use it only for this little task.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MSConfig. MSConfig only reads what's in the registry already. You need to add a registry entry in the appropriate location (which you can see easily in the Location column of MSConfig) or as an entry in the individual user's Startup group (again, available through MSConfig). There are literally hundreds of existing posts here about writing to the registry in the language of your choice, as well as doing so from an installer.

Comment: Yes, now that i know where i have to look at (Windows Registry) i will find an answer here for sure. Thanks.